# What is the most solid way to mount floating shelves?

Tags: mounting, shelving

I want to install a series of floating shelves to hold mostly books and some other heavy items in my living room.

I found this on Instructables where one use expansion bolt and 6mm thread bar for what seems like a very solid setup. I was wondering if the expansion bolt could be used in the wall studs as my walls are way too thin oterwise.

I also found this post here where one recommend to use Z-clip. Yet I am not sure how much weight a 12 inch deep shelve could hold which such a mount. [How can I mount heavy stuff on wooden studs?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49111/how-can-i-mount-heavy-stuff-on-wooden-studs)

What do you think is the most robust choice?

Comment: If you're referring to this instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-Floating-Shelf/ , then that's for concrete walls. I sincerely doubt you'd get good results with expansion bolts in wood. (Nor do I think that 6mm threaded rod is adequate for books, but I have no data to back that up.) Honestly, if a client asked me to build a floating shelf for books, I'd refuse out of fear that it would fail. Upside down brackets that are also bookrests, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a "french cleat". This is a technique where you cut a board into two pieces using a 45 degree angle. I used this to mount some cabinets and they are incredibly strong. It just depends on whether you can adapt that to the shelf you have. Good luck.

[image: Example French Cleat]

Comment: How much shelve weight do you think these can support? Let's say if the cleat was 2 feet long.

Comment: I think it would totally depend on your ability to find and screw into studs and whether or not you were willing to also add an adhesive behind it.  Here is a Google image search of French Cleats (https://goo.gl/8XOJzb). You can get an idea of the types of things people use them for. I've seen someone hanging from a cabinet they hung with a french cleat before but I cannot find that image now.